# ordering a list of dictionaries by date

Tags: python, sorting, date, dictionary

I have the following list:

```
l = [{datetime.date(2011, 4, 30): "Carrot"}, 
     {datetime.date(2009, 4, 12): "Banana"},
     {datetime.date(2012, 1, 1): "Corn"}]
```

I want a new list with the dictionaries ordered by date (earliest first):

```
l = [{datetime.date(2009, 4, 12): "Banana"},
     {datetime.date(2011, 4, 30): "Carrot"},
     {datetime.date(2012, 1, 1): "Corn"}]
```

I expect the answer involves `sorted` and `key` but I'm struggling to isolate the key of each dictionary to use as the comparator. In other questions which have posed a similar problem, the dictionaries take the form:

```
{'date':datetime.date(2009, 4, 12): "Banana"}
```

The addition of the `date` string seems to make the task easier but i'd like to avoid it if possible

cheers.

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary for each entry? why not a tuple ie. (datetime.date(2009, 4, 12),"Banana")

Answer (score 7):

Use the key of your inner dictionary as sort key. You can do this by passing a key getter function to `sorted` which pulls out the date key from your dictionary.

```
sorted(l, key=lambda v: v.keys()[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I had I couldn't actually get this code to work (TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing). On the advice of a couple of others who posted a response I decided to package this data using a tuple instead. This has proved a good move
and I've got the behaviour I want now.

Answer (score 3):

```
print sorted(l) 

[{datetime.date(2009, 4, 12): 'Banana'}, {datetime.date(2011, 4, 30): 'Carrot'}, {datetime.date(2012, 1, 1): 'Corn'}]
```

is actually doing the job in this case.

Choosing a more suitable datastructure like a tuple or a dict with explict keys for the date and the value would be of advantage here but as said: working out of the box using sorted().

Comment: TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict()

Comment: Doesn't mean it is correct. There is no guarantee that dictionaries must be ordered like that in every implementation.

Comment: Have changed to tuple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a list of tuple, or collect those data into a class. Anyway, to get an iterator of keys with the `.keys()` function, and get any member from it by converting it to an iterable and call `next()` on it:

```
l.sort(key=lambda p:next(iter(p.keys())))
```

If you're using Python 2.x, replace `keys` with `iterkeys`.

Comment: Couldn't get this code to work actually: when I assigned the output to a variable (v = l.sort(key=lambda p:next(iter(p.keys()))), it just returned None. Not to worry, I took your first piece of advice, changed it to a tuple, and all is now well. Cheers.

Comment: @Paul: `.sort()` is an in-place method. You *do not* assign the result to `v` (actually it does not return anything, which is why you got None). After calling `.sort()`, the list `l` will be sorted.